# Replicator+ Experimental Extruder Filament Slipping Error

Tags: print-quality, makerbot

I'm experimenting with MakerBot's new "Experimental Extruder" which essentially opens their software (MakerBot Print) to change traditionally "behind-the-scenes" settings like retract rate/distance, nozzle diameter, etc.

I am currently attempting to print with the following conditions:

- 0.8mm nozzle (brass)
- 0.6mm layer height
- 2 shells
- 5% infill
- 212 °C-215 °C extruder temperature
- The part is pretty much all an outer shell (see image)

[image: Top Perspective]

I know that the results of testing the Experimental Extruder with a larger nozzle often required a lower extrusion temperature and the retract rate/distance to be increased. While testing the Experimental Extruder, personally, I found success increasing the retract distance to 0.850mm.

I know that this issue can be resolved by adjusting the extruder profile, but I'm continually running into issues with self-resolving "Filament Slip" errors which inevitably result in "Filament Jam" errors. So, I'm obviously not making adjustments to the correct settings.

Here's the PrintMode file for reference:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "name": "TBM0115 Draft 0.8mm Nozzle 0.6mm LH",
    "settings": {
        "brimsModelOffset": 0.02,
        "doBrims": true,
        "doRaft": false,
        "extruderProfiles>0>defaultTemperature": 215,
        "extruderProfiles>0>extrusionProfiles>bridges>feedrate": 50,
        "extruderProfiles>0>extrusionProfiles>floorSurfaceFills>fanSpeed": 0.2,
        "extruderProfiles>0>extrusionProfiles>floorSurfaceFills>feedrate": 50,
        "extruderProfiles>0>extrusionProfiles>roofSurfaceFills>feedrate": 60,
        "extruderProfiles>0>extrusionVolumeMultiplier": 1,
        "extruderProfiles>0>nozzleDiameter": 0.8,
        "floorThickness": 1.2,
        "layerHeight": 0.6,
        "maxSparseFillThickness": 0.4,
        "modelFillProfiles>sparse>density": 0.05,
        "modelFillProfiles>sparse>pattern": "linear",
        "extruderProfiles>0>retractDistance": 0.9,
        "extruderProfiles>0>restartExtraDistance": 0.15,
        "doFixedShellStart": false,
        "extruderProfiles>0>extrusionProfiles>outlines>feedrate": 30,
        "numberOfBrims": 3,
        "numberOfInternalBrims": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: `results of testing the Experimental Extruder with a larger nozzle often required a lower extrusion temperature` is in contradiction with expectations, e.g. a nozzle/layer height combo of respectively 0.4/0.3 lays down 4 mm³ per 100 mm, a 0.8/0.6 combo delivers about 30 mm³ for that same distance!; this is a lot of heat that is dissipated and needs to be replenished. As the filament heating up time is shortened by the increased feed rate you should increase the temperature to get the filament center to heatup also. In fact your problems could be related to not heating up the filament too fast.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>As the comment section doesn't allow to use too many characters, I've converted the comment into a proper answer.</sub>

In the question is stated that:

> ... results of testing the Experimental Extruder with a larger nozzle
>   often required a lower extrusion temperature...

This is in contradiction with expectations. When the filament feed rate or volume increases, generally a higher temperature is required to heat up the filament because the resident time of the filament in the heatbreak and nozzle decreases.

As the filament heat up time is shortened by the increased feed rate you should either:

- **increase** the temperature to get the filament center to also heat up. In fact, all your problems could be related to not heating up the filament too fast (filament jam or slip). When the center of the filament is not soft enough, it will be harder to push through the nozzle, hence the slip and the clogging, or
- **decrease** the print speed, decreasing the print speed will increase the filament resident time.

As an example, a nozzle/layer height combo of respectively 0.4/0.3 lays down 4 mm³ per 100 mm, a 0.8/0.6 combo delivers about 30 mm³ for that same distance! This is a lot of heat that is dissipated and needs to be replenished. A reduction of print speed by a factor of 7.5 (30/4) will also address the increase in heat up time.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown! I'll try that approach and see if there's any improvement before I accept this.